# Could not figure out a SQL Query to relate both tables

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

Ok, I have two tables.

Table 'topic'

```
tid | posts 
------------
1       4
3       2
```

Table 'posts'

```
topic_id |  post
-----------------
1      xxxx
3      aaaa
1      dddd
1      ddsdss
3      rreer
1      gsdsd
```

My abstract query is like this:

```
select counter(*) as c 
from posts as p, topic as t 
where p.tid = t.topicid 
  and c != t.posts
```

This should return counter of all 'posts' table rows which matches with 'topic' table tid and also does not matche with Table 'topic' posts count.

Also I need to update the colum "posts" of topic with the counter(*) value if found different.

```
update topic set posts = (SELECT COUNT(*) from posts WHERE posts.topicid = topic.tid and topic.posts <> (SELECT COUNT(*) from posts WHERE posts.topicid = topic.tid))
```

I tried many ways to get this working, but could not figure out. Would really appreciate if anyone can explain a query for this case ?

---

Actually what I am trying do is this. I want to update posts counter of topic for all the matching topic ids between table if posts count of 'posts' table does not match 'topic' table posts counter. You get me ? I tried to play with your query, but it does other way of giving me 'topic' table rows instead which is not I want.

```
UPDATE topics SET posts = (
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM posts 
  WHERE topicid = (
    SELECT tid 
    FROM topics 
    WHERE topics.tid = topicid
 ) 
 GROUP BY topicid HAVING COUNT(*) <> (
   SELECT posts 
   FROM topics WHERE topics.tid = topicid
 )
) **WHERE tid = (
  SELECT topicid 
  FROM posts 
  WHERE topicid = (
    SELECT tid 
    FROM topics 
    WHERE topics.tid = topicid
  ) GROUP BY topicid HAVING COUNT(*) <> (
      SELECT posts FROM topics WHERE topics.tid = topicid
  )
)**
```

Comment: It is confusing, and you will get better results here by showing us sample data for the A and B tables, along with the output your expect to get from your query.

Comment: added more details. Thanks

Comment: Remove the `posts` column from the `topic` table. It's not a good idea to store data redundantly. You can always `select *` to get the count. For convenience you can write a view with a column for the count.

Comment: I cannot remove that as it services a purpose in our DB, and have no rights.

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you the topic and count

If you want to find the topics that are "wrong" then join this to the the count table

```
SELECT *
FROM topic
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT topic_id, count(*) as t_count
  FROM posts
  GROUP BY topic_id
) sub on topic.tid  = sub.topic_id
```

Then to see the ones that are different you can add a where

```
WHERE topic.posts <> sub.t_count
```

Comment: Can you update the query other way ? Like posts outside and topic inside. I need count of posts that matches the id and does not match counter of topics posts. Thanks

Comment: @DineshG if you add the where to my query that is exactly what it does

Comment: Actually what I am trying do is this. I want to update posts counter of topic for all the matching topic ids between table if posts count of 'posts' table does not match 'topic' table posts counter. You get me ? I tried to play with your query, but it does other way of giving me 'topic' table rows instead which is not I want. Hope this helps. Thanks

Comment: `UPDATE topics SET posts = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts WHERE topicid = (SELECT tid FROM topics WHERE topics.tid = topicid) GROUP BY topicid HAVING COUNT(*) <> (SELECT posts FROM topics WHERE topics.tid = topicid)) **WHERE tid = (SELECT topicid FROM posts WHERE topicid = (SELECT tid FROM topics WHERE topics.tid = topicid) GROUP BY topicid HAVING COUNT(*) <> (SELECT posts FROM topics WHERE topics.tid = topicid))**`

Comment: This is a version of code I am trying which is not a good one, but I wanted to show you what I am after. Thanks